# Add class to LI element depending on data-size attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using Gridster for Wordpress to control the arrangement of a masonry style grid layout. Gidster basically allows site admins to reorder / resize posts in realtime (see screenshot)

[image: Example of Gridster]

Now as a rule I would only like to use a number of grid sizes (1x1, 1x2, 2x2). The markup for the grid is output as the following:

1x1: `<li data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="gs_w">`

1x2: `<li data-sizex="1" data-sizey="2" class="gs_w">`

2x2: `<li data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2" class="gs_w">`

You can see the grid size is determined by the HTML 5 data attributes 'data-sizex' and 'data-sizey'. I would like to use Jquery check for these attributes on page load and add classes respectively..

For example an element with a grid size of 1x1 (data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1") would have a class of '1x1'

I believe I need to use attribute selector but am a little unsure as how to proceed.

```
$("li[data-sizex='1']")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use each to parse and get data elements to make the class

```
$('li').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass($(this).data('sizex') + "x" + $(this).data('sizey'));
});
```

**Edit** to limit the add class for specific li e.g descendant of a particular element as mentioned by OP in comment we can extend the selector.

```
$('.gridster li').each(function(){...
```

Comment: Great answer many thanks! I extended it a little by adding $('.gridster li').each(function(){. This stops all li's being affected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass($(this).attr('data-sizex') + "x" + $(this).attr('data-sizey'));
});
```